# Password confirmation Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple register form and i decide to add the feature of confirmation my password and it doesn't seem to check even if i type a different password!
 Is there an error in my code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name=c_password]').keyup(password_check);

});
function password_check(){  
var password = $('input[name=password]').val();
var c_password = $('input[name=c_password]').val();
if(c_password != password || c_password.length < 6){
    //alert("test");
    $('input[name=c_password]').parent().addClass( "has-error has-feedback" );
}else{
    $('input[name=c_password]').parent().removeClass( "has-success has-feedback" );

}
}
```

Thanks!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3217/

Comment: What are you expecting to happen if the passwords don't match?

Comment: I'd like the border of the input to became red

Comment: Did you remove url for reason? :)

Comment: Your password-checking logic seems fine. You just don't have any code in there that would actually do anything.

Comment: `$('input[name=c_password]');` doesn't **DO** anything. It's just a statement. And your ajax call also doesn't actually call anything. You don't provide a url, you just have a `success` handler which will never get called because you never actually DO anything there either.

Comment: so do I have to check with only javascript or should add url that does that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is almost right, except that you forget to remove the class has-error in case of correct the c_password.

```
$('input[name=c_password]').parent().removeClass("has-error")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3221/

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about that! and i update it now : http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3222/

Comment: You do not need to remove the class inside the if-then-else, because they are removed at the beginning of the function

Answer (score 1):

```
if(c_password != password || c_password.length < 6){
    //alert("test");
    $('input[name$=password]').parent().addClass( "has-error has-feedback" );
}else{
 ...
  (you need put a 'url' on ajax)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've just ommited some code. From what you've provided I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
if(c_password != password || c_password.length < 6){
    // This is the additional code
    $('input[name=c_password]').parent().addClass( "has-error has-feedback" );
}else{

    jQuery.ajax({
       success: function(response){
...
}
}
```

Something along those lines should highlight an error to the user. Don't forgot to validate server-side too, client-side is just for user convenience.

EDIT: actually, let's ignore that last edit :/

Comment: Not from me, not sure why that happened.